# How to make preg_match match a number followed by a dot?

Tags: php

I'm trying to make preg_match only match the first 2 chars, which is a number followed by a dot, but it seems to be matching any numbers..

```
$data = array('1. awesome', '3. not cool', '23423,12 is not suppose to match');

foreach($data as $array){
    if (preg_match('/^([0-9].)/', $array)) {
        echo $array, '</br>';
    }
}
```

is outputting:

```
1. awesome
3. not cool
23423,12 is not suppose to match
```

How come this is happening?

Comment: You need to escape the period, otherwise it's "Any character".

Comment: @JonStirling, ha.. all I can say. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You wrote `.` in your regex, which matches anything (it's a wildcard). You need to escape with a `\` it to match literal `.`:

```
<?php
$data = array('1. awesome', '3. not cool', '23423,12 is not suppose to match');

foreach($data as $array){
    if (preg_match('/^([0-9]\.)/', $array)) {
        echo $array, '</br>';
    }
}
```